# Why bootstrap form validation doesn't work on one webpage?

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have 3 web pages each page contains 1 bootstrap form. The forms are structured the same, but each has a different number of input fields and order in which they appear in the form.

The HTML page files, local JS files are all in the same folder(no sub-folders). The `<`head`>` on each page has the same assests.
The non-functional form has a text area and button that the other forms do not. I have tried commenting these out, but that didn't resolve the problem. I have tried removing the link to local CSS, that too made no difference in the issue.

When I check the html files with W3 validator I get one Error and 2 Warnings.
Error: Element legend not allowed as child of element form in this context. 
Warning: The date input type is not supported in all browsers. Please be sure to test, and consider using a polyfill. Commenting out the legend makes no difference.
I do have a date field in both the working and non-working forms.
When I look at dev tools in Chrome I don't see any errors.

I have tested on both Chrome and FireFox, so I don't think it is a browser specific issue.
Note this is all done on local machine and all coded using notepadd++. 
I know this would be a tremendous amount of code to post for review, but if required I will do so. I was hoping someone would have troubleshooting suggestion.

have created 2 jsbin. first link is page with non working form. Second link is page with working form. first link is https://jsbin.com/xuwuziy/edit?html,css,js,output . Second link is https://jsbin.com/luqatel/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: you don't need to post all the code, just an MCVE which can reproduce the issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance. In fact, the task of creating one might lead you to find the issue yourself if you're lucky. We can't tell you what your problem is if we can't see your code. You also haven't really described the actual problem in any detail. We just have a verbal description of your page (which is of very minimal use in debugging) and a vague "validation doens't work" statement.

Comment: ADyson. Sorry about the vagueness.When I say validation is not working I mean that as the user types in the inputs the red invalid state with the X and message are not working, nor are the green valid states with check mark
working either. I am presently not submitting these forms at all. I am just using the validation states to help the user input valid data.  I will look into mcve as suggested. Also maybe do a js bin.

Comment: I have created 2 jsbin. first link is page with non working form. Second link is page with working form.  first link https://jsbin.com/xuwuziy/edit?html,css,js,output  second link https://jsbin.com/luqatel/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: In the first one: `$('#cruise1').bootstrapValidator`. There's no element with id "cruise1" in the page. Did you mean `$('#quoteform').bootstrapValidator` since "quote1" is the id of the form element?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I  changed the form id from (#quoteform) to (# cruise1) and validation started working. So, these are two different forms on two different pages. How do I give these forms indivdual id and still get validator to work? Why is validator binding to just that id?

Comment: The validator is just binding to that one ID because that's what you told it. That's what the # selector does - looks for an element with that specific ID (IDs must be unique in any given page). I'm not sure I understand your question "How do I give these forms indivdual id and still get validator to work?". Your forms already do have individual IDs "cruise1" and "quote1", to be specific). Are you really asking how to use the same code to validate both forms?

Comment: Forgive me for my inexperience. I thought having the validator scripts and link in the `<`head`>` of each page would allow those  scripts to provide functionality to each indivdual form id.

Comment: well you have to tell it which form you want to validate, which is what the function which starts with $(<selector>).bootstrapValidator does (a page can contain multiple forms, after all), and each form can obviously have its own validation rules.

Comment: If you want the same code to validate both forms then you have to give both forms the same selector (either the same ID, or the same CSS class)

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much for clarifying all of this. How can I give an up vote?  Because these were just posted as comments, not answers.

Comment: I can write it up as an answer so you can upvote / mark as accepted - give me a couple of minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first JSBin: `$('#cruise1').bootstrapValidator(...`. There's no element with id "cruise1" in the page. Instead your form's ID is "quoteForm". Therefore the validator does not bind to it because it can't find an element with the "cruise1" ID.

Since you're including the same validation JS on both pages, in order to get the same code to validate both forms, you have to use a selector that can match to both forms.

There are two possible, simple solutions.

1) Give both forms an id of "cruise1". However, this may not be very descriptive of your quote form.

2) Give both forms the same class, and use *that* as the selector to initialise the validator. e.g.:

The form tags:

```
<form class="form-horizontal validatableForm" id="quoteform">
```

and

```
<form class="form-horizontal validatableForm" id="cruise1">
```

And the validator intialisation:

```
$('.validatableForm').bootstrapValidator( //...etc
```

This will initialise the same validation on all forms which match the given selector (i.e. all forms with that class). In any one page, in your situation, you might only have one form loaded with that class, but it means it will work when the code is included in both pages, and if for any reason you had two forms with that class loaded in one page it would bind those as well.

One last note, since you mentioned you were new to this: I hope you are implementing the same validation rules in your server side code (the code which deals with the submitted form data). Client-side validation such as you've used is very nice for user experience, but it's not secure - any user, especially a malicious one, or an automated spam-bot, can easily manipulate or bypass the JavaScript validation (most simply, by just turning off JavaScript) and try to send invalid or problematic data to the server. You cannot trust anything which comes from the client-side and must re-validate everything in order to protect your application and database.

Comment: I up voted your answer. Completely resolved my problem. I gave the forms the same class and unique #id. Included the class in the selector of the validator script. These were for demos.  Plan to use ajax and php to server side validate if demos meet client approval.